# Creating a stopwatch in Meteor.js

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm looking to create a simply stopwatch using meteor. At present I have a start and stop button and when start is clicked, it sets duration to zero and when stop is clicked it calcs the duration between start and end time and displays using a session variable. The simple code I have is as follows:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {

  startTime = 0;
  endTime = 0;


  Template.hello.helpers({
    displayDuration: function () {
      return Session.get('duration');
    }, 
  });

  Template.hello.events({
    'click #start': function () {
      Session.set('duration', 0);
      startTime = new Date().getTime()
      // console.log(startTime);
    },
    'click #stop': function () {
      endTime = new Date().getTime()
      var duration = endTime - startTime;
      Session.set('duration', duration);
      // console.log(endTime);
      console.log(duration);
    }
  });
}
```

My question is where to take it next? I'm looking to have the dom update every millisecond once the start button is pressed, but do not know how to implement that within the meteor framework.

Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: there is already sample app. please check https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-reactive-clock/

Comment: thanks! so, with that in mind would I set the session variable to the elapsedseconds variable in the readme code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [remcoder:chronos](https://atmospherejs.com/remcoder/chronos) package to create a *reactive* time variable and use that in your template helper.

**html:**

```
<template name="hello">
   duration: {{duration}}
</template>
```

**js:**

```
Template.hello.helpers({
  duration : function() {
    var start = Session.get('startTime');
    return start ? Chronos.currentTime(100) - start : null; // updates every hundred milliseconds
  }
});

Template.hello.events({
  'click #start': function () {
    Session.set('startTime', new Date().getTime());
  },
  'click #stop': function(){
    Session.set('startTime',null); // stops the timer
});
```

Comment: Excellent, really interesting way of approaching it, thanks for the input.